# Find email links in HTML using MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, regex

The HTML is stored within MySQL. What I need to do is find out if there are href links containing an email AND do not have mailto: prefixed to the email. Can this be done in MySQL?

This should be found by the query:

`... <a href="user1@example.com">user1@example.com</a> ...`

but not this one:

`... <a href="mailto:user2@example.com">user2@example.com</a> ...`

Note: I can use PHP/Python and parse the HTML if required, but I'm hoping there is a faster/easier way to do this by only using MySQL.

**Bonus Question:**

Can you use the above query in an update to add the missing mailto?

Comment: I should have added that this is in a potentially large HTML document, so the LIKE operator will return false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL REGEXP to find if there are any emails without the mailto.

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'column' REGEXP 'href\=\"[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\"'
```

I believe that regex should match anything in this format: href="asdf@asdf.com"
But it won't match: href="mailto:asdf@asdf.com"

Comment: You are correct that it finds `href="asdf@asdf.com"`, but this does not work for simple cases like `<a href="user@example.com">user@example.com</a>`. Is there a way to add a wildcard to the regex?

Comment: If you remove the ^ and $ characters from the regex It should find it any where.  With them there it's checking if the whole string matches.

Comment: Yep, just caught that myself. That query works for what I needed, thanks!